# Radius of Convergence for series in $z^{3n}$ using Cauchy-Hadamard formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

If
$∑
a_nz
^n$ has radius of convergence R, use the formula $R = \left( \limsup_{n \to \infty} | a_n |
 ^{\frac{1}{n}} \right)^{-1} $
to
find the radius of convergence of

$∑
a_nz^{
3n}$

I tried to solve this question using the ratio test, I got an answer of $R^{\frac{1}{3}}$, however, I am not sure how to solve it using Cauchy-Hadamard formula.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: The series is $\sum b_nz^{n}$ where $b_n=0$ if $n$ is not a multiple of $3$ and $a_{n/3}$ if $n$ is a multiple of $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $n\in\Bbb Z_+$, let$$b_n=\begin{cases}a_{n/3}&\text{ if }3\mid n\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{3n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nz^n$ and, for each $n\in\Bbb N$,$$\sqrt[n]{|b_n|}=\begin{cases}\sqrt[n]{|a_{n/3}|}=\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[n/3]{|a_{n/3}|}}&\text{ if }3\mid n\\0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$and therefore$$\limsup\nolimits_n\sqrt[n]{|b_n|}=\sqrt[3]{\limsup\nolimits_n\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}.$$

Comment: Thanks again sir, much appreciated